# Spring Statemachine is stateful?

Tags: spring-statemachine

I'm leaning ssm, blow is my demo config:

```
@Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<States, Events> config) throws Exception {
        config.withConfiguration()
                .autoStartup(true)
                .listener(listener());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states) throws Exception {
        states.withStates()
                .initial(States.S_1)
                .state(States.S_1, myAction(), null)
                .end(States.S_END)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(States.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions) throws Exception {
        transitions
                .withExternal()
                .source(States.S_1).target(States.S_2).event(Events.E1).action(myAction());
    }
```

I send two event to machine, but it run onece.

```
stateMachine.sendEvent(Events.E1);
stateMachine.sendEvent(Events.E1);
```

Does the ssm has state, how can I make it run stateless?

I just want to use it define my business procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Well it looks like event `E1` takes machine from `S_1` to `S_2`. Sending that event again will not do anything as machine is already in state `S_2` and transition from `S_1` to `S_2` cannot happen.

Not sure what you mean by making machine stateless?

Comment: I mean I want to SSM to define my business procedures, such as "create one order", needing first save order infomation to db,second send order ok email, third nofify processor process order. If another order create, it run the same procedures. But if state machine had change its state, it can't do that.

Comment: @Janne I understand that you are the lead developer of the spring state machine. A stateless state machine would only contain the transitions, actions and guards. The sate would be fully externalized and would be needed to be passed as attribute together with the event. The new state would be the return value. Please also have a look into my answer as this describes how the state machine is often used currently in the business, which is somewhat of a workaround.

Comment: @Janne I consider this topic as important and would be happy to have a more thorough exchange with you on this regard.

Answer (score 1):

state machine are statefull as goal is to react on a saved state... And event does state change...

I think in your case you might not want a state machine but a "simple" service layer

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately the spring state machine cannot be run stateless. I also hope that this feature will be implemented and that the state machine can be run with a fully externalized state.

So long **the solution is this**:

1. enable the spring state machine factory within the spring context:

```java
   @Configuration
   @EnableStateMachineFactory
   public class DomainStateMachineFactory extends
      EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {
    
    @Overrides...
   }
```

2. in your service layer process the events like this:

```java
   @Service
   public class DomainStateService {

     @Autowired
     StateMachineFactory<States, Events> stateMachineFactory;

     @Autowired
     private DomainStateMachinePersister persister;

     public StateTransitionEvaluationHolder processEvent( DomainEntity entity, Events event ) {

        // create a brand new state machine
        StateMachine<StatusDto, StatusEventDto> stateMachine = stateMachineFactory.getStateMachine();

        // load the the state of your domain entity into the state machine
        StateMachine<StatusDto, StatusEventDto> restoredStateMachine =
                persister.restore( stateMachine, entity );

        // register a state changed listener
        restoredStateMachine.addStateListener( 
            new DomainStateMachineListener( entity ) );

        // start the machine
        restoredStateMachine.startReactively().block();

        // process the event
        restoredStateMachine.sendEvent( Mono.just( MessageBuilder.withPayload( event ).build() ) )
                            .blockFirst();

        // stop the machine
        restoredStateMachine.stopReactively().block();
     }
   }
```

3. the loading of the domain entity state into the state machine is processed by these 2 classes:

a)

```java
   @Component
   public class DomainEntityPersist implements
       StateMachinePersist<States, Events, DomainEntity> {

     @Override
     public void write( StateMachineContext<States, Events> stateMachineContext,
         DomainEntity entity ) {

       throw new StateMachineException( "Persistence not supported. Persisted state remains in Domain Entity." );
     }

     @Override
     public StateMachineContext<States, Events> read( DomainEntity entity ) {

       ExtendedState extendedState = new DefaultExtendedState();
       return new DefaultStateMachineContext<>( entity.getState(), null,
                                             null, extendedState, null,
                                             DomainStateMachineFactory.MACHINE_ID );
     }
   }
```

and b)

```java
   @Component
   public class DomainEntityStateMachinePersister {

     DomainEntityPersist persist;

     StateMachinePersister<States, Events, DomainEntity> persister;

     public DomainEntityStateMachinePersister ( DomainEntityPersist persist ) {

       this.persist = persist;
       this.persister = new DefaultStateMachinePersister<>( persist );
     }

     public void persist( StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine,
         DomainEntity entity ) {

       try {
         persister.persist( stateMachine, entity );
       }
       catch ( Exception e ) {
         throw new StateMachineException( e );
       }
     }

      public StateMachine<States, Events> restore(
          StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine, DomainEntity entity ) {

        try {
          return persister.restore( stateMachine, entity );
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) {
          throw new StateMachineException( e );
        }
      }
    }
```

4. the listener looks like this:

```java
    public class DomainStateMachineListener extends
        StateMachineListenerAdapter<States, Events> {

      boolean changed = false;
      DomainEntity entity;

      public DomainStateMachineListener( DomainEntity entity ) {
        this.entity = entity;
      }

      @Override
      public void stateChanged( State<Statues, Events> from,
          State<States, Events> to ) {
        entity.setState( to.getId() );
        setChanged( true );
      }
    }
```

An exhaustive and more detailed explanation can be found here:

- [GuidePart1](https://developpaper.com/springstatemachine-enterprise-availability-level-development-guide-1-talk-nonsense/)
- [Guide1To8](https://developpaper.com/?s=spring%20state%20machine)